# Excel formulas to group and summarize data with smallest and largest in the group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the data in following format

[image]

The first two columns show the raw data. The blanks may or may not be there between different sets of data.

Column G,H,and I are the summary I want to achieve. I have tried using data->subtotal, group, ungroup features of excel, but none of them could result the following. I am not sure how to tackle this problem. The number of rows in raw data will be in the range of 200 to 500 items.

I can definitely do some manual work to separate the groups and then apply formulas for smallest and then largest values for them, but I am looking for complete automatic calculation of the summary. So that when I enter the data in the first 2 columns it should give the summary back in G,H,and I columns automatically.

**Edit:**
I have tried the array formula **=MAX(IF(A1:A101=A2,B1:B101))** in column C for finding out the Maximum for each group. The result is as follows as you can see the first row of each group is exactly what is required in the summary. Can we somehow remove the duplicates so that only first rows of each group will be left.

Still it requires me to put the formula in Column C and choose the range of the raw data. Which is not what I am looking for. I need something that calculates it automatically.

[image]

Comment: Via Excel it's difficult. Use VBA.

Comment: VBA is not an option for me. I am looking for function based solution

Comment: I have figured out how to put a column with Maximum values for each group. Now the problem is reduced to removing the duplicates without effecting the calculations of Maximum. Since the first row of each group is exactly what is required, therefore removing duplicates will give the required result. Not sure how to do it without affecting the maximum calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this scheme:

[image]

In the cell D2 put:

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",IF(A2="","",A2))
```

in the cell E2:

```
=IF(D2="","",VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$B$19,2,))
```

in the cell F2:

```
=IF(D2="","",B2)
```

and autocomplete...
You have the scheme in the picture. After you can use a filter on the D:F columns removing Blanks.
Eventually the D-F columns you can put in another sheet.

**Change road...** Sheet1 have raw data and you can do what you want (delete, insert, ecc).
On the second sheet you need to change like the picture:

[image]

In the D column you put a text with the address of the data and `Sheet1!A2` and with autocomplete make 1000 rows... after in the 3 column you substitute with:

```
Column E: =IF(INDIRECT(D3)=INDIRECT(D2);"";IF(INDIRECT(D2)="";"";INDIRECT(D2)))
Column F: =IF(E2="";"";VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(D2);Sheet1!$A$2:$B$1003;2;))
Column G: =IF(E2="";"";OFFSET(INDIRECT(D2);0;1))
```

and autocomplete.
Now people can compile only on the sheet1 as they want, and you have the total of the data on Sheet2...

Comment: It looks good but couple of questions. First of all I am not sure how many entries will be there, so how can we put the formulas in column E in advance? Secondly, if the formulas need to be put in columns after entering the raw data, then every time we will need to repeat the same steps? thirdly, the user is required to do manual work and sort, filter, and copy pasted the columns in another sheet, how can we automate this part as well?

Comment: IT's the reason I speek about VBA. It made all in automatic ... Question= the raw data arrive by automation? if yes you can only copy and paste a precompiled sheet. 1) with autocomplete you can the first time autocomplete for example 1000 rows. the formula work also if the rows are empty. 2) see my question. 3) Easly select column D-F and paste or you can have the base sheet with all the formula and paste in columns A-B the raw data.

Comment: I am going to try your formulas and now. Lets see how it goes.

Comment: The data will be entered one row at a time by a user. It will be automated later externally (nothing to do with this excel calculation)

Comment: did not understand your last comment completely. I am not aware of precompiled sheet. Also did not understand the concept of base sheet. Can you please explain it a bit further. I have tried your technique, it works as long as I apply it after completely getting the raw data and then entering the formulas, filtering the blank spaces etc. When I try to enter a new row after that, it does not give the required result. I have copied the formulas in 1000 cells.

Comment: Another possibility it's to have Raw data in a file that people can manage as they want, and the TOtal in another file. When you update the raw files nothing happen on the total, but when you open Total the data are updated. No operation of insert and delete shall be done when the total are open...

Comment: For your VBA suggestion, if we consider that and for simplicity if we assume that we want to calculate the summary after we collect the complete data, what it will take in VBA to automatically achieve the result.

Comment: Precompiled sheet: you have a sheet with the formula from D2 to F1000... from the Raw sheet you copy and paste (with value) from A2 to Ax (x shall be less of 1000, if you put 1000). When you insert a row you modify the formula reference. if you don't want that you need to make other modification on the sheet... VBA: you can have a button and update the sum when you want. You don't have problem with insert & delete.

Comment: I am not sure how to setup this two file system. Can you elaborate a bit further.

Comment: Ok so lets start with the simplest solution first. Assuming all data is present in sheet1. The pre-compiled formulas are present in sheet2. I copy the column A,B from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Then what do I need to do? repeat all the steps or it will just magically show the summary?

Comment: I have tried the first one and recorded a macro in excel to do the filtering and copying the data to another sheet. The only problem is to make that macro work automatically, when the data is copied in column A. Is there any possibility to do that?